# How to Concatenate Bytes

Tags: java

I have an array of Bytes. How do I concatenate them? E.g.

```
Byte mem[] = new Byte[4];
mem[0] = aa;
mem[1] = bb;
mem[2] = cc;
mem[3] = 00;
```

I want to return one hexadecimal number:
`aabbcc00`

Comment: Do you want a `String` or an `int`?

Comment: That is not valid Java code. Did you mean `mem[0] = 0xaa;`? --- Also, I sure hope you meant to use `byte[]`, not `Byte[]`.

Comment: If you wanted one 4-byte hex number, why not use `int num = 0xaabbcc00;`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Byte mem[] = new Byte[4];
mem[0] = aa;
mem[1] = bb;
mem[2] = cc;
mem[3] = 00;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
     System.out.print(mem[i]);
  }
```

You can use this for loop to get ouput `aabbcc00`.